# How can I get a line count for this grep command. Need number only, not all instances

Tags: ruby

I want to get a number count of the instances that contain the words. Don't need for all of the lines to display.

```
puts File.foreach('filename').grep /word looking for/
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can just use count:

```
p File.foreach('filename').grep(/word/).count
```